# Trying to send ARC (Arcade City) tokens via MEW and encountering issues

Tags: ether, tokens, myetherwallet

I'm trying to move some ARC tokens from one place to another but encountering an error.

Link to transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd350ac4b5eba650957c9a086f851f1914bec0fe4808566bdc5fa26e0e0d9d80a

I'm receiving the following error on multiple attempts: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]

According to the Arcade City whitepaper, tokens should be able to be moved around the second you take possession of them.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

did you already get this fixed in the meantime? Easiest is to convert your ARC to SWT and hold on to these ;) Some guidance here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ON5NLUQDFVM